# Add multiple same length time-series data frames into one column

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, addition

Want to sum one variable within fifteen data frames into one column by date.

Tried converting them all into xts but had a challenge converting them back to numeric from a factorial.

```
library(xts)
ts1<-as.xts(ts(c(1:12),star=c(2015,1),freq=12))
ts2<-as.xts(ts(c(13:24),star=c(2015,1),freq=12))
ts3<-as.xts(ts(c(13:24),star=c(2015,1),freq=12))
str(ts4 <- c(ts1, ts2,ts3))
```

Also looked into tibble vignette but was unable to add them together properly. Also tried using rowsum but only works when data is in one data frame. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this produces what you're looking for. The `param_df` would be a dataframe that contains the N, mean, and sd for each pair of distributions.

```
# Generate some fake parameters
param_df <- data.frame(n_1 = sample(50:100, 10, replace = T),
                       mean_1 = sample(5:10, 10, replace = T),
                       sd_1 = sample(1:9, 10, replace = T),
                       n_2 = sample(50:100, 10, replace = T),
                       mean_2 = sample(5:10, 10, replace = T),
                       sd_2 = sample(1:9, 10, replace = T),
                       variable_name = paste0("variable_", 1:10), 
                       stringsAsFactors = F)

# Function that will generate the distributions and calculate statistics
my_function <- function(n_1, mean_1, sd_1, n_2, mean_2, sd_2, var_name){
  samp_A <- rnorm(as.numeric(n_1), as.numeric(mean_1), as.numeric(sd_1))
  samp_B <- rnorm(as.numeric(n_2), as.numeric(mean_2), as.numeric(sd_2))
  var_score <- (mean(samp_A) + mean(samp_B)) / 2
  var_range <- sd(samp_A)
  return(c(Variable = var_name, Score = var_score, Range = var_range))
}

# Apply the function to the param_df by row, passing each column as an argument to the function
df <- apply(param_df, 1, function(params) my_function(params[1],
                                                      params[2],
                                                      params[3],
                                                      params[4],
                                                      params[5],
                                                      params[6],
                                                      params[7]))
# Convert to a dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
```

Note that the code here calculates the "score" differently than in your code above. I'm assuming that you wanted to divide the sum of the means and add the mean of A and half the mean of B.